# Java Spring - Styling on-page goes crazy

Tags: java, html, css, spring, web

I'm trying to build a taxi web application using Java Spring. I have the website ready (I made it using a template) but when I try to implement the login process, the styling on the page go crazy, everything from the fonts to the images. The login page works, but the site doesn't look good at all :( Do you have any idea what the problem can be? To specify, when I put my website in a "public" folder inside the resources, everything looks fine but I can't implement the login process.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the template engine to render a web page, you need to categorize the resources.Static resources(such as CSS and JS)  are stored in `static`  and template files are stored in `template`.

Answer (score 0):

If java works, you can open the browser and Press F12-->network->css to check if you css is loading fine?
e.g [image: css check]

also if your css path is wrong , F12 --> console, maybe already logout some 404 error

Comment: It looks like it cannot find the files even if the files path is correct

Comment: import css like this , not "text/html"
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{path}" type="text/css">

Answer (score 0):

Now, the styles are found but cannot be executed?

Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:9040/login' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).